# How to calculate an expression based on names in the second level of a mult-index column

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe with a multiindex columns object where the first level defines some category and the second level defines a component of a formula.  Consider the dataframe `df`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list('XYZ'), list('kap'), ])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 5, size=(2, 9)), columns=mux)

df

   X        Y        Z      
   k  a  p  k  a  p  k  a  p
0  1  4  3  4  3  3  4  3  4
1  2  4  2  3  4  4  1  4  3
```

I want to calculate the the formula `k * a ** p` for each of `X`, `Y`, and `Z`

I could assign to a separate dataframe

```
x = df.X

x.eval('k * a ** p')

0    64
1    32
dtype: int64
```

But how do I get this for `X`, `Y`, and `Z` all at once.

The final result should look like:

```
    X    Y    Z
0  64  108  324
1  32  768   64
```

Comment: Are you on 0.20? I get `TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()` when running this on 0.20.

Comment: `'0.20.3'` is what I'm on

Comment: I get in `0.20.3` same error.

Comment: Where are you getting the error?

Comment: `x.eval('k * a ** p')`

Comment: `df.X.eval('k * a ** p')` gives same error?  Ok, weird!

Comment: @JohnGalt Yes.  You know I have answers.  I'm just bored.  Post answers, get some action going on the pandas tag

Comment: `df.X.eval('k * a ** p')` same error

Comment: @jezrael/COLDSPEED, any other experiments you guys can concoct to figure out wth is going on?  Works fine for me.  This seems like a bug somewhere.

Comment: tested in python 3.5 under win7

Comment: Tested on python3.4***, Ipython5, MacOS,btw this code works fine in 0.18. I think it's a bug for sure.

Comment: What are the `dtypes` of `df`?  and of `df.X`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1).** One way would be `groupby` on `level`

```
In [1841]: df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(lambda x: x[x.name].eval('k*a**p'))
Out[1841]:
    X    Y    Z
0  64  108  324
1  32  768   64
```

**2).** Another, loop by levels.

```
In [1818]: pd.DataFrame({c: df[c].eval('k*a**p') for c in df.columns.levels[0]})
Out[1818]:
    X    Y    Z
0  64  108  324
1  32  768   64
```

Comment: `groupby` is clever!

Answer (score 2):

Solution without eval:

```
d = {c: df[c].assign(A=lambda x: x.k*x.a**x.p)['A'] for c in df.columns.levels[0]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d)
print (df1)
    X    Y    Z
0  64  108  324
1  32  768   64
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

```
df.stack(0).eval('k * a ** p').unstack()

    X    Y    Z
0  64  108  324
1  32  768   64
```

---

**Option 2**

```
df.swaplevel(0, 1, 1).pipe(lambda d: d.k * d.a ** d.p)

    X    Y    Z
0  64  108  324
1  32  768   64
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit ugly, but involves sorting the columns and then calling `.mul` and `.pow`.

```
df2 = df.sort_index(level=[0, 1], axis=1)

v = df2.loc[:, (slice(None), 'a')]\
                  .pow(df2.loc[:, (slice(None), 'p')].values, 1)
out = df2.loc[:, (slice(None), 'k')].mul(v.values, 1)

print(out)

    X    Y    Z
    k    k    k
0  64  108  324
1  32  768   64
```